# Obj-c: Shift uitextview up when keyboard activated?

Tags: ios, objective-c

When my user types in my textview, I want the textview to shift up so that the keyboard doesn't cover it. I'm using the below code, but nothing is moving upwards, and the keyboard continues to cover my textview. How can I fix this?

**ViewController.h**

```
 @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *replyField;
```

**ViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];


[self.replyField setReturnKeyType:UIReturnKeyDefault];

}

- (void)dismissKeyboard
{
    [self.replyField resignFirstResponder];

}

- (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
    [self animateTextView: YES];
}


- (void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
    [self animateTextView:NO];
}

- (void) animateTextView:(BOOL) up
{
    const int movementDistance = -250; // tweak as needed
    const float movementDuration = 0.3f; // tweak as needed
    int movement= movement = (up ? -movementDistance : movementDistance);
    NSLog(@"%d",movement);

    [UIView beginAnimations: @"anim" context: nil];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState: YES];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration: movementDuration];
    self.view.frame = CGRectOffset(self.inputView.frame, 0, movement);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Comment: You are not setting the text field delegate.

Comment: @ElTomato Correct :) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Looks there are 2 bugs in `animateTextView` method:

- original value -250 causes wrong moving direction with `(up ? -movementDistance : movementDistance)`
- `self.view.frame = CGRectOffset(self.inputView.frame, 0, movement);`
  will change the self.view's frame, not the textView's.

The improvements(Codes tested in my Xcode):

```
- (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView{
    [self animateTextView:textView isUp:YES];
}

- (void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView{
    [self animateTextView:textView isUp:NO];
}

- (void)animateTextView:(UITextView *)textView isUp:(BOOL)up{
    const int movementDistance = 250; // tweak as needed
    const float movementDuration = 0.3f; // tweak as needed
    int movement = (up ? -movementDistance : movementDistance);
    NSLog(@"%d",movement);

    [UIView beginAnimations: @"anim" context: nil];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState: YES];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration: movementDuration];
    textView.frame = CGRectOffset(textView.frame, 0, movement);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

//To close keyboard when click Return key.
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text {
    if ([text isEqualToString:@"\n"]) {
        [textView resignFirstResponder];
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

And like @El Tomato said, remember to set delegate for the textView:

```
[self.replyField setDelegate:self];
```